# What a gift for the Energy Being that has everything?

Tags: energy-beings

Is there anything Energy Beings want to make them stand out among the other Energy Beings? Socks are always a fallback option, of course, but there has to be something more original than that...

Comment: Welcome to the site, Don. I would strongly suggest you [edit] your question to include details concerning the society, culture, needs, etc. of the species you have in mind. Barring this, we cannot provide an answer to your question. Regardless, I consider this to be highly opinion-based. I would suggest taking the [tour] and reading up on [Risk Factors](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3206/6986).

Comment: The problem with the word *best* is that it makes questions vague and opinion based if you don't provide the parameters by which you are measuring what is good and what is bad.

Comment: Took out the word "best".  Any gift suggestions for an Energy Being are now fair play.

Comment: @DonMynack this did not make the question better. It is harder to judge what would be a good answer or a bad one. What we need is a way to measure those, based on the question.

Answer (score 2):

Do energy beings *eat* energy? Does some kinds of energy taste like pickles and some kinds taste like ice cream?

Maybe an energy being might like a nice tasty treat, like smoked campfire heat, or tangy falling water. Or how about a great big charge of pure clean hydrogen-helium fusion.

Perhaps you could take an energy being out to a nice dinner, like, at a volcano or a forest fire.

Everybody gotta eat but if you wanna be nice you can make it a party.

Comment: I'm gonna go with [pickles](https://www.jimonlight.com/tags/electric-pickle-experiment-explanation/)

Comment: Any energy being with any kind of taste wouldn't be caught dead eating  processed energy. It has to be locally produced, free-range energy or nothing. Good suggestions, though!

Answer (score 2):

Prisms!   Not sure why, but if I was an energy being I think I'd enjoy refracting myself as a hobby.

Comment: That's a great idea!

Answer (score -1):

maybe some sort of energy booster something that can make the energy being more powerful, or at least something that can change the beings color.